# Create web map tiles from large images

Tags: raster, gdal, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, gdal2tiles

I have 70Gb of raster data from drone photography that I need to serve  via Openlayers.

The data is currently provided as georeferenced jpegs each is 175Mgb in size.

What is the best strategy to cut these into manageable tile sizes for serving via the web.

I have access to the gdal suite and was looking at the gdal2tile.py script. Can this be run on a set of tiles to produce a directory of georeferenced smaller tiles?

Comment: Mapcruncher (old) but chops up the tiles with zoom levels http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22420 works with openlayers tiles like http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Local_Tiles_Example

Comment: Do these images need to be orthomosaiced? or are the images already orthophotos?

Comment: They are already orthophotos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run gdal2tiles.py on a multiple images, use gdalbuildvrt to build a virual raster from those images first. Then you can run gdal2tiles on the .vrt file.

```
gdalbuildvrt -o merged.vrt file1.jp2 file2.jp2 ....
gdal2tiles.py merged.vrt output_folder/
```

If you are running it on large files, check out the [enhanced version of the script](https://github.com/pramsey/gdal2tilesp) that uses parallel processing.

Comment: Update: This has worked but appears to have warped my images to EPSG:900913. The basemap I am using is EPSG:27700. Is there a way of creating a 27700 TMS grid using gdal2tiles.py. If not then I am back to the drawing board.